# Background image has been replaced with boxes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

At some time today, the background image on U&L has changed to a strange looking grid of gray boxes.

https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/unixmeta/img/site-background-image.svg?v=adf85a88e194

[image: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/unixmeta/img/site-background-image.svg?v=adf85a88e194]

This grid doesn't seem to have been there yesterday.

I suspect this isn't intentional, as the image just looks wrong.

Comment: Ahah, oops! We were moving some image assets around and I messed this one up.

Answer (score 6):

This is amazing, and will be fixed in the next build, coming up very shortly. We moved a ton of theming assets around, and I assumed incorrectly that this SVG background image was sized appropriately. I've added a proper `background-size` to the CSS so things'll look right.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. And a huge thank you to whoever changed the background to remove those distracting little dots we used to have!

Comment: @terdon it looks like the dots are gone from the main question section, but they're still behind the outside edges (left nav, top, bottom, etc).  Just in case there was an intentional removal, it was incomplete.

Comment: @JeffSchaller ah crud, yes, they're back. They were gone for a while which was very pleasant.

Answer (score -5):

## New Upgrade

This is by-design. This is StackExchange's new theme for the site which is supposed to make it look like feeder-marks and scan-marks on a scantron! The logic here is that Linux and Unix are older, more mechanical, and not cool. And, what could be less cool than a scantron?

Hopefully it makes all the neckbeards feel right at home. If not, StackExchange has volunteered to copy over the posh minimalist boxless theme from Apple.StackExchange.

[image]